# Show button if string in html table == something with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

Im trying to display the x button only if the email == the current users email address using javascript.

[image: my table]

This is how i populate the table

```
            var user = mymail@gnail.com
            function getOrders() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/get-orders",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response = data["code"];
                        data = data["data"];
                        var dataArray = data.orders;

                        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                            tr = $('<tr/>');
                            tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='cancelOrderButton;'>X</button>" + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].room + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].user + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].real_name + "</td>");


                            $('.table1').append(tr);
                        };
                    }
                });
            };
```

And here's the HTML

```
                <table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: And where is the current user email stored?

Comment: Right now its just hardcoded. Later it will get it from the backend

Comment: So what exactly is your problem here? It should be as simple as comparing varialbes/strings: `if(current_email === dataArray[i].user{...})` in the loop and if it's matching append the button

Comment: `tr.append("<td>" + (user === dataArray[i].user) ? "<button...>X</button>" : "" + "</td>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosed the mymail@gnail.com with quotation marks. I also added an if statement between the appending of td's which verifies first if they match the hard coded email.

```
if (dataArray[i].user == currentUser) {
  tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='cancelOrderButton;'>X</button>" + "</td>");
}else{
  tr.append("<td></td>");
}
```

```js
var currentUser = 'mymail@gnail.com'

function getOrders() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/get-orders",
    success: function(data) {
      response = data["code"];
      data = data["data"];
      var dataArray = data.orders;

      for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        if (dataArray[i].user == currentUser) {
          tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='cancelOrderButton;'>X</button>" + "</td>");
        } else {
          tr.append("<td></td>");
        }
        tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].room + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].user + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].real_name + "</td>");


        $('.table1').append(tr);
      };
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Replaced   if (data[i].user == currentUser) with 
  if (dataArray[i].user == currentUser)
and deleted the 2nd
tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='cancelOrderButton;'>X</button>" + "</td>");

Comment: Corrected the if statement according to your comment. Np, good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

While constructing the array, you can toggle that particular button:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {    
    var tr = $('<tr/>'),
        buttonTd = $('<td/>'),
        xButton = $('<button/>').attr(id, 'cancelOrderButton' + i).value('X').hide();

    tr.append(buttonTd.append(xButton));
    tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].room + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].user + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].real_name + "</td>");

    $('.table1').append(tr);
    if (user === dataArray[i].user) xButton.show();
};
```

HTML

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```